# Solr based Sitecore Blog Module

Tags: solr

Do we have any Solr based blog module available in Sitecore? We have looked for different blog solution but didn't find any blog module based on Solr.

Comment: I voted to close this answer because it really is too broad, but I don't want to leave you without a direction to go in. I believe that you may be limiting the modules you can use by looking for the wrong criteria. There are many blog modules available for Sitecore and the majority of them rely on Content Search. Lucene and Solr are both providers that Content Search has native support for. Most modules will work with either and those few that don't can most likely be customized to work with the desired one. Blogs are pretty straight-forward and you can always roll your own too, if need be.

Comment: Agreed. Also largely opinion based answers come from these types of questions.  This is better posted on the #Solr Sitecore Slack channel

Comment: Probably not worded properly but I needed to know if blog module works with Solr. Thanks for information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WeBlog works with Solr. You can find more information at https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/issues/172 that talks about the issue, but then in the comments below, SMRaxa and varitw provide the necessary fixes.

We have successfully used their approach.

Comment: Not sure if WeBlog was updated to use MVC, but xBlog supports both Web Forms and MVC. Also, its an enhanced  module with inputs from Alistair Dennis as well. You can try it, it can be downloaded from https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/XBlog.aspx?sc_lang=en

Comment: WeBlog has MVC as well, yes